# How can I count summed rows as one row in LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select user's notifications according to these rules:

- all unread notifications
- always 2 read notifications
- at least 15 notifications *(by default)*

Here is my query which gets user's notifications ids:

```
( SELECT id FROM events             -- all unread messages
  WHERE author_id = ? AND seen = 0  
) UNION
( SELECT id FROM events             -- 2 read messages
  WHERE author_id = ? AND seen <> 0
  ORDER BY date_time desc
  LIMIT 2                              
) UNION
( SELECT id FROM events             -- at least 15 rows by default
  WHERE author_id = ?
  ORDER BY seen, date_time desc
  LIMIT 15   
)
```

And then I select the matched ids in query above plus other info like this: *(I don't want to combine these two queries because of some reasons in reality)*

```
SELECT SUM(score) score, post_id, title, content, date_time
FROM events
GROUP BY post_id, title, content, date_time
ORDER BY seen, MAX(date_time) desc
WHERE id IN ($ids)
```

It works and all fine.

---

**The problem is:** When the first query selects 15 rows which all have the same post_id, then the second query will sum them up and show it as **one** notification row with total-scores.

I guess I have to add that `SUM()` also in the first query? And that `GROUP BY`? Any idea?

---

An example of the problem, if an user earn 15 upvotes, the first query selects them as 15 notifications, and the second query make it one notification. How can I get 15 separated notification? (those notification which will be summed in the second query should be counted as one notification in the first query, how?)

Comment: a table structure with example data (provide a sqlfiddle.com) and expected output as ascii data table would tell us much more then a query and a explainment of the problem.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Still isn't it clear enough? I re-asked it again after improving it.

Comment: It's properly quicker because when you use a union you don't have any indexes.

Comment: Sorry, it’s not clear to me. 1) If you want them as separate notifications, why are you grouping them? 2) with `LIMIT` you get _at most_ 15 notifications (plus the unique ones from the other `UNION` branches), not _at least_. What is the purpose of limiting them?

Comment: @Dario 1) I wand 15 separated notifications, probably they be 20 rows (5 rows will be summed and shown as one notification if they are all belong to one pos. 2) that "at least" means if all unread and those two read notification are less that 15, it will add some more notification to the number of 15, anyway Im not good in English, perhaps I shouldn't say at least

Comment: Is it so difficult to provide, as @RaymondNijland already asked, some example data and expected ouput? I’m afraid I still don’t understand what you want to group and sum up, and what you want to keep separate...

Comment: You say you want to select a user's notifications, but you select data for one author_id. So user = author. Correct? Then there are events, messages and notifications. You say you want two read notifications, you select two read events and you comment this as two read messages. So event = message = notification. Yes?

Comment: Then you want "all unread notifications". That can be zero or ten or thousands of records. Then you want to select "two read notifications". You are selecting the lastest two. But what to do if there is only one or no read message at all for the author? At last you want "at least 15 notifications". So why not simply select all messages? Are you maybe saying that you don't want to select any data if you don't find at least  13 unread notifications (13+ unread + 2 read >= 15)? I don't understand. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes Correct....

Comment: Ok look, I want 15 latest notifications if all are read. If there are unread notifications, then I want to select all of them (if they are less than 15, then the rest should be rea notifications until the number of 15). If the number of unread notifications are more that 15, then I want to select all of them plus 2 read notifications. So always there should be at least 2 read  notifications. And always the number of selected notifications should be at 15 (if there is) or more (if the number of unread notifications is more than 15)

Comment: I see. Your first query solves this elegantly (though I'd make the first `UNION` a `UNION ALL`). Anyway, the seconds query looks a bit wrong. It seems you want one result row per `post_id`. Is this the case? Then your `GROUP BY` clause is wrong, because it also includes `date_time`, `title`, and `content`. For each `post_id` you want the total `score` and the maximum `date_time`. But which `title` and `content` do you want to show?

Comment: And your problem seems to be that you mention rules on notifications (records in your events table), but actually you want rules for posts (referenced by `post_id`). So re-word the rules, e.g. for rule #1: All posts for which exists no read notification. Or: All posts for which exists exists at least one unread notification. etc. Once this is done, we can see how to apply these rules.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner nope, rules are fine and all works as well. The problem is **selecting notifications in two steps**. In the first step I just select notifications ids (without grouping anything), and the second step gets the info of those ids (in this step I use group by on score column). So sometimes the first step doesn't know that the second step will merge all 15 ids (or 13 ids or whatever, I mean the ones that have same post-id), because there isn't any group by in the first step. The first step thinks has selected 15 notifications, while maybe some of them get summed in the second step.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner So all I'm trying to do is adding a group by in th first step to make it intelligent about grouping, to tell it "select 15 groups, not 15 ids"

Comment: You stated a rule which notifications to consider, so as to end up with at least 15 notifications. This rule is wrong, because you can end up with less than 15 posts. This is not what you want. You want a rule that results in at least 15 posts. State this rule.

Comment: It seems strange, too, that you only select some notifications per post, but then you sum the score as if this were the total score for the post. It's just a partial score sum kind of left to chance, though. And as mentioned you say you'd get only one result row when there is just one `post_id`, but this doesn't match your `GROUP BY` clause. So either your statement or the `GROUP BY` clause must be wrong.

Comment: Actually you said an interesting rule about the number of notifications per posts .. Seems you're getting close to understand what I want *(also thank you for spending your time one my problem)* .. Ok, lets say it this way: The second query gets 15 ids *(assuming the first query returned 15 ids)*, and it returns 1 or 2 or 3 or utmost 15 rows. Right? Because it sums some rows which have the same `post_id, title, content, date_time`, How can I modify the first query, to make sure the the result of second query is always 15 rows? @ThorstenKettner

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm Martin teammate .. and I really don't know why we cannot convey what we mean :-(

Comment: Currently everything is working as well, but sometimes user A earns 15 vote on the same post from the same voter on the same time (assuming it is possible). In that case, the first query returns the id of those 15 rows, and the second query sums all of them and we see just one notification in the inbox list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you finally want 15 rows per group, you should have rules on groups rather than on messages in my opinion.

You can aggregate your data per group and then check whether the group shall be in your results. You'd do this in the `HAVING` clause with conditional aggregation, i.e. an aggregation function used on a conditional expression. This is one method to count unread messages for example:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN seen = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

This is another:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN seen = 0 THEN 1 END)
```

(The `ELSE` branch is omitted and defaults to null, which is not count.)

In MySQL these expressions are even simpler, because `false` equals 0 and `true` equals 1. So in MySQL you'd count with:

```
SUM(seen = 0)
```

You can use other aggregation functions, too:

```
HAVING MAX(seen = 0) = 0 -- no unread messages

HAVING MIN(seen = 0) = 1 -- no read messages
```

Now let's select all groups with at least one unread message:

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS score, post_id, title, content, date_time
FROM events
GROUP BY post_id, title, content, date_time
HAVING SUM(seen = 0) > 0;
```

(We could also use `HAVING MAX(seen = 0) = 1`.)

Now your `UNION` approach to get all groups with at least one unread message, plus as many other groups as necessary to get at least 15 groups:

```
(
  SELECT SUM(score) AS score, post_id, title, content, date_time, SUM(seen = 0) as unread
  FROM events
  GROUP BY post_id, title, content, date_time
  HAVING SUM(seen = 0) > 0
)
UNION
(
  SELECT SUM(score) AS score, post_id, title, content, date_time, SUM(seen = 0) as unread
  FROM events
  GROUP BY post_id, title, content, date_time
  ORDER BY SUM(seen = 0) DESC, date_time DESC
  LIMIT 15
)
ORDER BY (unread = 0), date_time DESC;
```

If you want the single IDs for above groups, then use `IN`:

```
SELECT id
FROM events
WHERE (post_id, title, content, date_time) IN
(
  SELECT post_id, title, content, date_time
  FROM (<above query>) q
);
```

Comment: Thank you, seems good, just one thing, I don't understand this rule: *"let's select all groups with at least one unread message"*, why at least one unread message? We should select all unread ones plus at least  two read ones.

Comment: What **group** rule would you state to consider all unread messages? If I select all groups that have at least one unread message, I'm considering all unread messages. As to the rule: "at least two read messages", I still don't know what that rule is good for. Can you make a group role for this? Would "at least two groups with at least one read message each" suit you? Then add such query with `UNION`.

Comment: At this point I leave the rest for you. Think of rules you want applied and use the techniques shown. If all this gets too complicated, you may want another approach still, which would be: read messages or groups in the desired order without limit, then in PHP fetch row by row until you are satisfied with what you've read.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you, upvote. Also a sexy approach came to me. [Using a subquery](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/b52b3636033ad0b419d156919de16a3b). However I couldn't write the subquery part in my query. The subquery should return only one id, but my current subquery returns a set of ids, do you know how can I make it force to always return the smallest id? (noted that this would be as the third part of the union in the query in my question)

Comment: As my last question, do you know why [this](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/1a492c0d6a1ae6afbca8bdd1ca10d659) throws *"Invalid use of group function"*? And how can I fix the syntax?

Comment: This: `GROUP BY type, post_id, table_code, comment_id, context ORDER BY date_time DESC` is invalid. MySQL may lket this slip, but it makes no sense. How can you order by `date_time`? It's not in the `GROUP BY` clause, so which `date_time` for a group? You could `ORDER BY MIN(date_time) DESC` or `ORDER BY MAX(date_time) DESC`, whichever you need.

Comment: This: `SELECT e.id, e.table_code [...] HAVING  e.id >= MIN(ids)` is even worse. Without any `GROUP BY` you aggregate all records to one single row. In this single row, there is no one `e.id` or one `e.table_code`; there are multiple. This query is invalid SQL, but MySQL let's this slip normally and simply picks some `e.id` and `e.table_code` arbitrarily. So with `HAVING  e.id >= MIN(ids)` you say: Pick just one of the IDs randomly and compare it with the smallest ID, if these happen to be the same, show me a result, otherwise not.

Comment: By the way: The error is a MariaDB error. You tagged your request MySQL. The two are kin, but still different DBMS.

Comment: Ah, ok, did you understand what I'm trying to do? I want to select the smallest id of the set of those 15 groups ids, and then select all notifications which are both belong to the user and **bigger that id**. Can you please help me write that query?

Comment: Sorry I don't have much time at hand now. One more thing regarding your query though: You have a subquery in the `SELECT` clause. This is supposed to get one value only. But in that subquery you `GROUP BY` some columns which usually gets you several rows. You even select an arbitrarily picked ID per group. Please read up on aggregation and `GROUP BY`. As a rule of thumb: Every column in your query should either be in the `GROUP BY` clause or be aggregated with `MIN`, `MAX` etc.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. Also I've added `MIN(id)` in the sub query to avoid selecting an arbitrarily picked ID per group

Comment: That is still **per group**. As you are struggling so much with the queries, it may be worth to pay an expert to do the work. Thus you'd get good queries and you'd learn from this, too.

Comment: I live in Iran and everything is embargo for us. We don't even have a credit card, anyway, probably I need to find an expert in Iran. ok thank you anyway :-)

Comment: Do you think is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689571/6381081) what I was looking for? In the tests, I see lots of duplicates rows ..

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer, but too long for a comment:**

You think the rules are all clear, but are they? Let's say it's not at least 15 but only at least 5 rows you want in your final results. From the following table you'd want the IDs 1, 2, 3, and 4, because these are unread. But what about the others?

```
id | score | post_id | title | content | date_time           | seen
---+-------+---------+-------+---------+---------------------+-----
1  |    10 |      11 | hello | it's me | 2018-01-11 12:34:56 |    0
2  |    20 |      22 | hello | it's me | 2018-01-12 12:34:56 |    0
3  |    30 |      33 | hello | it's me | 2018-01-13 12:34:56 |    0
4  |    40 |      44 | hello | it's me | 2018-01-14 12:34:56 |    0
5  |    50 |      11 | hello | it's me | 2018-01-11 12:34:56 |    1
6  |    60 |      22 | hello | it's me | 2018-01-12 12:34:56 |    1
7  |    70 |      44 | hello | it's me | 2018-01-14 12:34:56 |    1
8  |    80 |      55 | hello | it's me | 2018-01-05 12:34:56 |    1
9  |    90 |      55 | hello | it's me | 2018-01-05 12:34:56 |    1
```

Does it matter that there are read notifications for the same groups? Does it matter that they are newer than notifications 8 and 9? Or will you simply add ID 8 (or 9?) to the set and be done?

No matter whether you select IDs 1, 2, 3, 4, and say 8 or you select all rows, you'd end up with five groups. So please tell us which IDs you'd select and why.

Comment: Now I understand I don't even know what I want :-(

Comment: Ok, in your table, all rows should be selected, because all of them are less than 15 rows

Comment: No, above I said we make this 5 instead of 15 rows to simplify my example. So if we were looking for only 5 final rows: Would you select just 1,2,3,4,8 (or 1,2,3,4,9) or others still or all IDs?

Comment: Ah, ok. Just 0 in the seen column means unread? (I'm suspect  because usually unread messages are in the bottom)

Comment: This is just a table of records. There is no order. Yes, seen = 0 = unread.

Comment: Ok, then these ids should be selected: (1, 2, 3, 4 as unread) (5, 6 as two read)

Comment: Then you have four groups in your result. I thought you want five. And what makes you decide for IDs 5 and 6 anyway?

Comment: ok I forgot about grouping, my bad, this ids should selected (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) in other word 5 groups

Comment: Why do you select IDs 5, 6, and 7? Why don't you select ID 9? And it doesn't help much if you say "I want this ID and this and this", as long as you don't say why. What are the rules by which you decide for records? So far I know only one ID rule: All unread messages. Please tell me the rule(s) for the other IDs, which we need to get to five groups.

Comment: Ok, 1,2,3,4 should be selected as unread ones, 5,6 should be selected as two unread ones (I call it a padding of older notifications), from now on, we should just complete 5 groups, we have 4 groups by now, so we should select id 7, still 4 groups, we add id 8. Yay, 5 groups completed. We cannot call id 9 belonging to "recent notifications", because it isn't unread, and 5 groups are completed.

Comment: Also the table example you provided is awesome. I enjoyed. It helped me to understand what I want exactly. Also your personality seems nice, it's about one day you're involved with my problem. I don't know what should I say, thank you so much.

Comment: For me the rules are still not clear. We tell the DBMS to get all unread records. That's IDs 1, 2, 3, and 4. Four groups. We want five. So we tell the DBMS to grab another record. Which? By what rule have you decided that the next record to select is ID 5? Is it because it is the oldest read message? Or because 5 is your favorite number? What is the rule?

Comment: Emm yeah, in my query there is ORDER BY date_time DESC. So id 5 is supposed to be the most recent read notification.

Comment: The most recent = newest

Comment: The most recent would be ID 7 of 2018-01-14. So you'd select 1,2,3,4,7,6,5 and then either 8 or 9 because these are the oldest, both at the same time. This is a strange rule because some groups will be complete and others may not. Do you really want to aggregate incomplete groups in your final query? You sum the scores, but you don't know whether this is the real total or just a partial sum. For the last group you'd get score 80 or 90 simply depending on which record you decide for. I find this strange. And I cannot think of any reason why one would select such data.

Comment: The summed scores would have no meaning. I am also surprised you `group by post_id, title, content, date_time`. How likely is it that two events occur in the same second with the same title and content on the same post? Aren't these undesired duplicates? If so, why do you even allow them in the table? All this seems just weird. Can you explain what you actually want to achieve? I mean not a technical explanation but a real-life explanation? The technical rules seem strange.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the value variety of data_time column. Sorry, and yes according to date_time column the ids you listed is right. And you are right, In my case the last group may be incompetent. But that's what SO does, you will see a notification with +30 rep because of latest 3 upvotes for an answer you wrote, while that answer may earned 10 upvotes in total. But those old +70 rep wouldn't be called as recent notifications. However now I believe you are right, a incomplete group is meaningless kinda and it would be better to make 5 complete groups. Is doing that hard?

Comment: I'll think of a solution. Unfortunately I don't have time now. The solution will be to focus on groups not on IDs in the first place.

Comment: Also in reality the scenario is totally different. Yes I have an unique index on some columns which doesn't let such row get insert. It would be awesome if you knew PHP, in that case I could add you to my repository to see the real problem, but now that's the only way  I simplify my problem.