# How can I extract all rows of groups?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table:

```
// notifications
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
| id | money  | post_id   | user_id | belongs_to_user_id |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
| 1  | 5      | 1         | 123     | 101                |
| 2  | 10     | 2         | 123     | 101                |
| 3  | -2     | 4         | 456     | 101                |
| 5  | -2     | 2         | 456     | 101                |
| 6  | -2     | 3         | 123     | 101                |
| 7  | 5      | 4         | 789     | 101                |
| 8  | 10     | 4         | 789     | 101                |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
```

And I select a set of grouped rows using this query: (the last three groups)*

```
SELECT * FROM notifications
WHERE belongs_to_user_id = 101
GROUP BY post_id, user_id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Here is the current result:

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
| 5  | -2     | 2         | 456     | 101                |
| 6  | -2     | 3         | 123     | 101                |
| 7  | 5      | 4         | 789     | 101                | -- the eighth row is grouped with this
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
```

---

While the expected result is a set of extracted groups like this:

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
| 5  | -2     | 2         | 456     | 101                |
| 6  | -2     | 3         | 123     | 101                |
| 7  | 5      | 4         | 789     | 101                |
| 8  | 10     | 4         | 789     | 101                |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have a subquery to return the last 3 user_ids. JOIN with that result.

Comment: @jarlh Is your solution based on `user_id` column? Doesn't sound right.

Comment: Well, how could I know? Chose another column, if you want to, sub-query is still the way to go!

Comment: The grouped rows should be in the subquery? @jarlh

Comment: i don't beleave you want to group your result - ordering is enough. grouping is for merging two rows and calculating sums or counts

Comment: You need `SELECT post_id, user_id FROM...` in your subquery.

Comment: I'm with niyou here. While you are talking about *groups*, your expected result simply shows the last four *records*. So what do you group by for?

Comment: And you seem to completely misunderstand what `GROUP BY` actually does, as your `SELECT *` plainly shows. Your query mainly does this: For each post_id/user_id pair pick one of their IDs, one of their money values and one of their belongs_to_user_id. Then only show the rows with the three greatest arbitrarily picked IDs. That doesn't make much sense obviously.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I want to use such GROUP BY in the third section of the first query of (this)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659584/how-can-i-count-summed-rows-as-one-row-in-limit] to solve the problem. Is there any better idea?

Comment: From what you show above you only want `select * from notifications order by id desc limit 3`. I don't understand what you mean with groups. And I don't understand that other request either. I'll leave a comment there, too.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ok here is the scenario: I get user notifications for in two steps, in the first step ids, and since some notifications have score, then I group then using aanothe query (step two). The problem is, sometimes the second query merges all rows (because all are relates to one post and should be sum) and then the user sees only one notification in his list. Now I want to add that grouping thing to the first step too t avoid this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this either. You group them because they have score? I have no idea what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: Take a look at notifications in SO, some notifications are comments (which don't have any score, so they shouldn't be grouped), but some notifications are vote (which have score and will be grouped the ones that belong to the same post) @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM notifications n JOIN
     (SELECT n2.post_id, n2.user_id
      FROM notifications n2
      WHERE n2.belongs_to_user_id = 101
      ORDER BY n2.id DESC
      LIMIT 3
     ) nn
     ON nn.post_id = n.post_id AND nn.user_id = n.user_id
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Nothing in your problem suggests `GROUP BY`.  You seem confused by the terminology of SQL.