# How can I force a subquery return only one row?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT e.id, e.table_code,

 ( SELECT MIN(date_time) date_time,
         SUM(score) score,
         type,
         post_id,
         table_code,
         comment_id,
         context
   FROM events 
   WHERE author_id = 32
   GROUP BY type, post_id, table_code, comment_id, context
   ORDER BY MIN(date_time) DESC
   LIMIT 15 ) g

FROM events e
WHERE e.author_id = 32 AND e.date_time >= MIN(g.date_time)
ORDER BY seen ASC, date_time DESC
```

It throws:

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Any idea how can I fix it?

---

I'm trying to:

1. Select 15 groups of latest events (the smallest id of groups)
2. And then Select all events (which are belong to a specific user) that have a bigger id that that smallest id

Noted that, probably "group" be vague. Actually it's about notifications, so the notifications which has the same post id (and are related to vote) will be summed and named as one group.

Comment: try removing the () from select.

Comment: One *row* <> One *column*. Move this `g` into FROM.

Comment: On a bit different topic, take a look at selecting groups by criteria, without using subqueries - https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/03/14/how-to-find-the-max-row-per-group-in-sql-without-subqueries/.
EDIT: I previously posted a wrong link. It's the right one now.

Comment: a sub query within a select should only return one column, one row!

Comment: You cannot return more than 1 column from a sub-query in the `select`. You should move your sub-query to the `from` and join it to your events table.

Comment: Firstly,please check your select statement in subquery ,it should contain one column only

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` the sub-query instead!

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  I would suggest you ask another question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok [I did it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692126/how-can-i-omit-a-column-from-select-statement-while-using-it-into-having-clause), Does it make sense?

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . Your subquery is returning multiple columns, it is not at all clear what you intend.  Your `WHERE` refers to `MIN()`.  It is not at all clear what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `Sub-Query`.

Try this:

```
SELECT e.id, e.table_code,g.*
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(date_time) date_time,
         SUM(score) score,
         type,
         post_id,
         table_code,
         comment_id,
         context
   FROM events 
   WHERE author_id = 32
   GROUP BY type, post_id, table_code, comment_id, context
   ORDER BY MIN(date_time) DESC
   LIMIT 15 ) g ON e.table_code = g.table_code AND e.date_time >= g.date_time
WHERE e.author_id = 32
ORDER BY seen ASC, e.date_time DESC
```

Comment: `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

Comment: Should be `e.date_time >= g.date_time`. But move it to ON clause.

Comment: @jarlh, Hope now it looks fine.

Comment: Looks better now!

Comment: `#1052 - Column 'date_time' in order clause is ambiguous`

Comment: You know, it doesn't have any syntax error, but I guess it has a logical problem. Since the result contains lots of duplicate rows.