# How can I omit a column from SELECT statement while using it into HAVING clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT e.id, (SELECT MIN(u.id) id
        FROM (SELECT MIN(id) id
            FROM events
            WHERE author_id = 32
            GROUP BY type, post_id, table_code, comment_id, context
            ORDER BY MIN(id) desc 
            LIMIT 15) as u
        ) as indicator_id
FROM events e
WHERE author_id = 32
HAVING e.id >= indicator_id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

It works as well and returns two columns: `id` and `indicator_id`.

I need to just get the `id`. How can I omit `indicator_id`? As you can see, I need to use `indicator_id` into `HAVING` clause. So I cannot omit the whole subquery. Just I need to move it somewhere else than `SELECT` statement. What's the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the subquery to the `having` clause.  As Gordon answered, you're using the `having` clause as a second `where`, which only MySQL supports.  It's better to add the second condition to the `where` with `and`:

```
SELECT e.id
FROM events e
WHERE author_id = 32
    AND e.id >= (SELECT MIN(u.id) id
        FROM (SELECT MIN(id) id
            FROM events
            WHERE author_id = 32
            GROUP BY type, post_id, table_code, comment_id, context
            ORDER BY MIN(id) desc 
            LIMIT 15) as u
        ) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Based on your comment, this would be a bit simpler.  It selects the 15 posts with the highest event id:

```
SELECT  id
FROM    events
WHERE   author_id = 32
        AND post_id IN
        (
        SELECT  DISTINCT post_id
        FROM    events
        ORDER BY
                id DESC
        LIMIT   15
        )
```

Comment: Oh right .. thank you, upvote. Just one thing, someone told me *"your query makes no sense (specially that **grouping** part)"*. Is he right in your opinion?

Comment: It looks a bit unusual, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Long story .. It's 2 days I'm involved this :-( ..! I'm trying to get the 15 recent user's notifications. The point is, latest 15 rows doesn't mean latest 15 notifications. Since notifications will be summed (their score) if they are related to the same post. So I need to select latest 15 groups.

Comment: Also I'm trying to understand your second query. It returns just 1 row, while your first query returns 26 rows.. do you think they are similar?

Comment: Thought you might be looking for 1 item, I've removed the old second query.  The first one shouldn't return more than 15 rows... is there more than one row with the same `id`?  Also added a simpler query

Comment: Good, your second query seems good, but then I need to extract all ids of those groups.

Comment: Updated to include all event ids for the 15 posts with the most recent events

Comment: Great, thx .. [as my last question](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/3ebbd6d32c0512a576f4a1f4d81ad81a), any idea?

Comment: `limit 1` is the obvious way to return the first row, or `limit 1 offset 3` to return the third row

Comment: `limit 1` is totally different. It means the minimum value from the beginning until now, but selecting the minimum of `limit 15` means the minimum value of the latest 15 ones.

Comment: Well then the `limit 15` in an inner query and  `limit 1` in the outer query with different ordering makes sense (like you're doing in the post)

Comment: eemm .. honestly I cannot imagine what you're saying. And I'm really interest to know what you mean exactly? If you think it is an other approach, then it would be great if you add it as another query to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but you can move the logic to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT e.id
FROM events e JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(u.id) as id
      FROM (SELECT MIN(id) as id
            FROM events
            WHERE author_id = 32
            GROUP BY type, post_id, table_code, comment_id, context
            ORDER BY MIN(id) desc 
            LIMIT 15
           ) u
     ) e15
     ON e.id >= e15.id
WHERE e.author_id = 32
ORDER BY e.id DESC;
```

I prefer this formulation because it is standard SQL.  Your use of the `HAVING` clause is a MySQL extension.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the tip, upvote. Also, do you believe the query makes no sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can also declare a table and insert indicator id record into it and use it in your query. I know this is too long but just one more way to do it.

```
 Declare @indicatoridtable table
(
  @indicatorid datatype 
)

Insert into @indicatoridtable
SELECT MIN(u.id) as id
  FROM (SELECT MIN(id) as id
        FROM events
        WHERE author_id = 32
        GROUP BY type, post_id, table_code, comment_id, context
        ORDER BY MIN(id) desc 
        LIMIT 15
       ) 


 SELECT e.id
 FROM events e 
 ON e.id >= (select top 1 @indicatorid from @indicatoridtable )
 WHERE e.author_id = 32
 ORDER BY e.id DESC;
```